# How to update the model from the data entered in the form after submit in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I have a form in Struts2 with different types of fields. When I enter data into the form and submit it, no data entered are valued and in the `ActionSupport` class they are `null`. Below a sample of my problem

**`struts.xml` :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="do" />
    <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />
    <constant name="struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire" value="name" />
    <constant name="struts.i18n.encoding" value="ISO-8859-1" />
    <constant name="struts.i18n.reload" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.configuration.xml.reload" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.locale" value="fr" />
    <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="100000000000" />
    
    <package name="default" extends="tiles-default" namespace="/">

        <interceptors>
        
            <interceptor name="params-filter"
                class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParameterFilterInterceptor" />
            <interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="exception" />
                <interceptor-ref name="alias" />
                <interceptor-ref name="servlet-config" />
                <interceptor-ref name="i18n" />
                <interceptor-ref name="chain" />
                <interceptor-ref name="model-driven" />
                <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
                    <param name="maximumSize">11204928</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="static-params" />
                <interceptor-ref name="conversionError" />
                <interceptor-ref name="params" />
                <interceptor-ref name="prepare" />
                <interceptor-ref name="validation" />
                <interceptor-ref name="workflow" />
                <interceptor-ref name="userAware" />
            </interceptor-stack>
                    
        </interceptors>
        
        <default-interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />

        <global-results>
            <result name="technicalError" type="chain">
                errorAction
            </result>
            <result name="sessionInvalidError" type="tiles">
                sessionInvalid
            </result>
            <result name="blank" type="tiles">blank</result>
        </global-results>

        <global-exception-mappings>
            <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception"
                result="technicalError" />
            <exception-mapping
                exception="com.omb.service.exception.UserSessionInvalidException"
                result="sessionInvalidError" />

        </global-exception-mappings>
        
        <package name="omb" extends="default" namespace="/omb">
            <action name="*OMBAction" class="com.omb.MyAction" method="doMyAction">
            <result name="ok" type="tiles">maPage</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**JSP file :**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net/el" prefix="display"%>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<s:url value="/windowfiles/dhtmlwindow.css"/>" type="text/css" />



<script language="javascript"><!--
mes scripts
--></script>
<s:form action="valoriseHiddenOMBAction.do" theme="simple" id="hiddenForm">
    <s:hidden name="champ1" value="%{champ1}"></s:hidden>
    <s:hidden name="champ2" value="%{champ2}"></s:hidden>
</s:form>

<table height="100%" width="100%" border="0">
    <s:form action="doOMBAction.do" name="ombForm" id="idOmbForm" theme="simple">
        
        <s:hidden name="user.userId" value="%{user.userId}"></s:hidden>
        <s:hidden name="period.periodId" value="%{period.periodId}"></s:hidden>
        
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input  type="button"  value="download" onclick = "javascript:location.href='afficheOMBReport.do';"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="10%"><label ><s:text name="champ1.label"></s:text></label></td>
            <td width="4%">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="10%"><label ><s:text name="champ2.label"></s:text></label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <s:select cssStyle="width:200" list="listChamp1" id="idChamp1"
                    value="champ1.identifiant" listKey="identifiant" listValue="label"/>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <s:select cssStyle="width:200" list="listChamp2" id="idChamp2"
                    value="champ2.identifiant" listKey="identifiant" listValue="label"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input  type="button"  value="Afficher les valeurs" onclick = "javascript:location.href='afficheValuesOMBAction.do';"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </s:form>
</table>
```

**Java files :**

**`Champ.java` :**

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.omb;

public class Champ {

    private Integer identifiant;

    private String label;

    public Champ(Integer identifiant, String label) {
        super();
        this.identifiant = identifiant;
        this.label = label;
    }

    /**
     * @return the identifiant
     */
    public Integer getIdentifiant() {
        return identifiant;
    }

    /**
     * @param identifiant the identifiant to set
     */
    public void setIdentifiant(Integer identifiant) {
        this.identifiant = identifiant;
    }

    /**
     * @return the label
     */
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    /**
     * @param label the label to set
     */
    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

}
```

**The `MyAction` class:**

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.omb;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

/**
 * @author ombinte
 * 
 */
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {

    private Champ champ1;

    private Champ champ2;

    private List<Champ> listChamp1;

    private List<Champ> listChamp2;

    public String execute() throws Exception {

        listChamp1 = new ArrayList<Champ>();
        listChamp1.add(new Champ(1, "valeur1"));
        listChamp1.add(new Champ(2, "valeur2"));

        listChamp2 = new ArrayList<Champ>();
        listChamp2.add(new Champ(3, "valeur3"));
        listChamp2.add(new Champ(4, "valeur4"));

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String doMyAction() {

        System.out.println("ID Champ 1 = " + champ1.getIdentifiant());
        System.out.println("Label Champ 1 = " + champ1.getLabel());
        System.out.println("ID Champ 2 = " + champ2.getIdentifiant());
        System.out.println("Label Champ 2 = " + champ2.getLabel());

        return "ok";
    }

    /**
     * @return the champ1
     */
    public Champ getChamp1() {
        return champ1;
    }

    /**
     * @param champ1 the champ1 to set
     */
    public void setChamp1(Champ champ1) {
        this.champ1 = champ1;
    }

    /**
     * @return the champ2
     */
    public Champ getChamp2() {
        return champ2;
    }

    /**
     * @param champ2 the champ2 to set
     */
    public void setChamp2(Champ champ2) {
        this.champ2 = champ2;
    }

    /**
     * @return the listChamp1
     */
    public List<Champ> getListChamp1() {
        return listChamp1;
    }

    /**
     * @param listChamp1 the listChamp1 to set
     */
    public void setListChamp1(List<Champ> listChamp1) {
        this.listChamp1 = listChamp1;
    }

    /**
     * @return the listChamp2
     */
    public List<Champ> getListChamp2() {
        return listChamp2;
    }

    /**
     * @param listChamp2 the listChamp2 to set
     */
    public void setListChamp2(List<Champ> listChamp2) {
        this.listChamp2 = listChamp2;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your values are all `null` - for example `champ1` is `null` and you are trying to set `champ1.label`. You need to initialise your values to something either using the `preparable` interceptor/interface or the constructor. The `params` interceptor is fired _before_ `execute()` is called.

Comment: Please include the rendered HTML for the select tags; is the `"name"` attribute being rendered?

Comment: And ofcourse the select tag doesn't provide the value for the label, try use the hidden field or don't submit labels.

Comment: What is the equivalent of JSF "Update model value" in Struts2 ? an interceptor?

Comment: @OusmaneMINTE I didn't see how JSF is related to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The model is an `Action` class in your case, because you don't implement `ModelDriven`.

When you submit the form you should specify the `name` attribute which contains the value of the bean's property name of the action class. The bean is populated via the [`params` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/parameters-interceptor.html) using OGNL to access the bean properties.

In your code hidden fields aren't populated because you don't have such properties in the action bean.

Other input fields aren't populated because they doesn't have `name` attribute.

To fix the issue you should create properties and *accessors*, to *initialize* them so, OGNL would not catch NPEs trying to access them.

In the JSP add `name` attribute to `s:select` tag. For example

```
<s:select cssStyle="width:200" list="listChamp1" id="idChamp1"
  name="champ1.identifiant" listKey="identifiant" listValue="label"/>
```